# Changing tmp directory fastest and safest way possible?

Tags: 14.04, server

I have a Ubuntu server 14.04 that are running some popular game servers. I can't afford to take them offline for long (No longer then 30 minutes).

I know there are multiple ways to do this, and the question has been asked on here multiple times, but I'm really looking for the safest and fastest possible way to do this.

I'm running on a OVH dedicated server, which has /root at 20 gigs and is currently full and /home with the rest of 2TB.  I already have a /home/tmp dir for MySQL, but I'd like to have /tmp also linked to /home/tmp so applications actually work correctly.

I did come up with this I'd like to try, but I need to make sure this is correct and wouldn't break anything:

```
mv -r /tmp/* /home/tmp; rm -r /tmp; ln -s /tmp /home/tmp
```

Is this right? I'm really worried about the symlink part. I want the original /tmp to be linked to /home/tmp.

Also would I be able to run this on my server without having to boot in recovery mode? Here are some information about what's running on the server:

- Apache, MySQL installed. MySQL tmp dir is already in /home/tmp.
- Game servers run java, actually am getting an error from initializing these servers that one file is currently to full.